# Angular Reactive Forms Reset Checkbox Values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I've an array of boolen values

```
const DOList = [true, false, false, true, true]
```

```
 const formControls = this.DataList.map(controls => new FormControl(false))
 this.selectDataConceptForm = this.fb.group({
      dataOwnerList: new FormArray(formControls), //5 checkbox controls
 });
```

Now I want to reset the values for `dataOwnerList` based on the values of `DOList` array

```
  for (const temp of this.DOList) {
     console.log('temp', temp);
    this.selectDataConceptForm.get('dataOwnerList').patchValue(temp, {
          emitEvent: false,
     });
   }
```

I tried the above solution but it didn't work it throws an error saying

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
at FormArray.patchValue (forms.js:4162:1)
```

I wanted to check and uncheck checkboxes with the values provided in `DOList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patchValue() method of a FormArray expects an array of values to patch, but you are passing it a single value from the DOList array in each iteration of the loop. This is why you're getting the error "value.forEach is not a function", because a single value is not iterable.

You can use the setValue method of the formarray to pass your array values:

```js
const DOList = [true, false, false, true, true];
const formControls = this.DataList.map(controls => new FormControl(false));
this.selectDataConceptForm = this.fb.group({
  dataOwnerList: new FormArray(formControls), //5 checkbox controls
});

// Set the values of the form array to the values in the DOList array
const doFormArray = this.selectDataConceptForm.get('dataOwnerList') as FormArray;
doFormArray.setValue(DOList);
```